# Display images from a folder in asp.net mvc using c# razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I have attached a folder to my project solution explorer (ASP.NET) that includes all the images I may retrieve their names from the database for output. Images names stored in the database as paths:

`<img src="~/@item.Logo" width="120" height="120" />`

the problem is that i am not getting the images displayed in the browser! when I output the value of @item.Logo and copy/paste it in the HTML tag the images were shown!

can anyone tell me what is the wrong thing i am doing here ?

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow! Can you show us the error? (http 404, http 500?) And can you show us the emitted html thats present in the browser?

Comment: no error is shown, this is what i get in my browser [link] (http://s13.postimg.org/3rmx83jcn/image.png)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Url.Content()` helper:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/item.Logo")" width="120" height="120" />
```

`~` sign means root directory of solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@model IEnumerable<YourModelClass>

@foreach (var item in Model){
<img src='"PathOfYourFolder" + @Url.Content("DatabaseImageFieldName")' />}
```